# Error in mo file with Zend Translate

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation

I'm using Zend Translate on a project I'm working on, and from the last week or so, whenever I  add a new string to the .po file, the scripts breaks giving the following error:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=1) state=0 in C:\www\web\application\languages\pt_PT\application.mo on line 132

But if I change the string that I want to translate to anything else, it starts working.

And if I add another string to translate, the file starts to work again.

I'm using *Poedit* to manage the translations, and the translations I'm inserting don't have any `"` or `'`.

Using the Validate tool in *Poedit* doesn't produce any errors.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question it's to old but here is how I solved this.

I have latest version of ZF1 1.12.20 (Discontinued). I tested everything but for me the solution was clean .po file by removing all “” especial quotes and \t characters in origin translation (English) and after that all works perfectly.